# OS detection is not working using NMAP

Tags: window, nmap

I am trying to detect the OS using `nmap`, but it does not recognize it.
The error I am getting is:

> Skipping SYN Stealth Scan against xx.xx.xx.xx because Windows does not
>   support scanning your own machine (localhost) this way. Skipping OS
>   Scan against xx.xx.xx.xx because it doesn't work against your own
>   machine (localhost)

Here is the command I used:

```
nmap -vv -O xx.xx.xx.xx > c:\out.txt
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/427437/why-doesnt-os-scan-work-against-your-own-machine

Answer (score 3):

The message is being shown you is very clear. *Windows does not support scanning your own machine (localhost)*. In [nmap webpage](http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html) You can find more information about nmap and Windows, for example:

> You cannot generally scan your own machine from itself (using a loopback IP such as 127.0.0.1 or any of its registered IP addresses). This is a Windows limitation that we haven't yet worked around. If you really want to do this, use a TCP connect scan without pinging (-sT -Pn) as that uses the high level socket API rather than sending raw packets.

In Linux You can do it.